# Show $(XX')^{-1}= PD^{-2}P'$, where $X = PDQ'$ is a thin SVD

Tags: matrices, inverse, svd

$X$ is $n \times p$ dimension matrix.

$X = PDQ'$ is a thin SVD, where $P$ is $n \times r$, $D$ is $r \times r$, and $Q$ is $p \times r$.

Here is what I tried:

$$(XX')^{-1} = (PDQ'QDP')^{-1} = (PD^2P')^{-1}$$

but since $P$ is just an orthonormal matrix, i.e., $P'P = I_{p}$ but $PP' \neq I_{n}$. How do I pull $P$ out from the inversion?

I'm not sure if it helps to list the source - I encounter this question when I was reading Shao's [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-40/issue-2/Estimation-in-high-dimensional-linear-models-with-deterministic-design-matrices/10.1214/12-AOS982.full) page 814 and 815.

Comment: Orthornormal matrix or [semi-orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix)?

Comment: Are you sure $P$ is not square?

Comment: What is the size of $X$?

Comment: If $XX'$ is invertible, $X$ must have full row rank. Therefore $r=n$ and $P$ is a square orthogonal matrix.